# Mathematical model on which current computers are built

Tags: turing-machines, computer-architecture, machine-models

It is said that "The Turing machine is not intended as practical computing technology, but rather as a hypothetical device representing a computing machine. Turing machines help computer scientists understand the limits of mechanical computation." [Wikipedia]

So on which model current machines are built?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The one closest to typical CPUs is probably the *register machine* or *random access machine* ([RAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_machine)). A RAM has

- an infinite number of registers, each of which stores an arbitrarily large number,
- a set of operations on these registers (typically $\{+ 1, = 0\}$),
- a programming language including these operations as well as control structures for looping/branching (until/if some register holds $0$) and
- a program counter pointing to the next operation (in some program).

Real CPUs are quite similar, with some changes:

- There are only finitely many registers (which may exist only virtually), and each stores only numbers of bounded size.
- There are more operations.

Apart from that, it's very close indeed. It is common to extend the RAM model to account for [memory hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_hierarchy), which makes results a lot more applicable.

Comment: I think that the [Random-access stored-program (RASP) machine model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_stored-program_machine) is even closer to an everyday computer

Comment: What Raphael said is not quite true: you are not allowed to store arbitrarily large numbers. In fact, in the RAM-model every register/memory cell can store $O(\log n)$ bits of information. Still this means that, the larger your input, the larger your machine word-size. This is of course not true for computers.

Comment: @A.Schulz: if you are going to criticize the RAM model in that way, you should also criticize Turing machines for having infinite tapes. These models are fine as they are because they idealize reality (very large but limited resources) in a mathematically useful way (approximate "very large" with "infinite" in order to study certain aspects of computation which are not about limited resources).

Comment: @AndrejBauer: I never criticized the RAM model.  Scaling is an important concept for all reasonable powerful models of computation. Otherwise we would be stuck with regular languages. However, technically speaking, a computer has limited resources and is therefore a finite state machine/finite automaton.

Comment: @A.Schulz That may depend on who is talking, and about what they are talking. In computability theory, such a restriction is more of a hindrance than of relevance. In complexity theory, it sure is relevant; the specific restriction then depends on the cost model one wishes to work with.

Answer (score 3):

[Von Neumann machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_architecture), and if you prefer something more mathematical, look instead at [RAM machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_access_machine).

Comment: That is a computer *architecture*, not a mathematical model.

Comment: "I need to add another sentence." -- that's a dead give-away that this should have been a comment, not an answer. Do you want to extend your post, or should I convert it?

Comment: Raphael is not right. Comments can be long, the answer can be as simple as 'Yes'. If it is a comment or answer is not a matter of length but a matter of content.

Comment: The answer is fine as it stands because it completely answers the question. Von Neumann's machines (let us not quibble over "machine" vs. "architecture") were designed specifically for the purpose of building actual computers. And since Wikipedia does a good job of describing them, I do not see what else I could say. It's not my fault the question has an easy answer.

Comment: @MassimoCafaro: what precisely is the difference? Von Neumann's designs are every bit as mathematical as Turing machines. Do not confuse a particular presentation with the mathematical idea. For example, Turing machines can be described in terms of "tapes", "heads" and "control states", or in terms of "a set of quadruples" and a "transition function". Even though one of them sounds more "mathematical", they are both mathematics.

Comment: @Andrej Bauer: the fundamental difference is that mathematical models not only describe systems or phenomena, but also allow reasoning about them in order to infer new knowledge and gain insights. Turing machines, RAM etc allow $reasoning$ about computability, and all of these models are polynomially related (i.e. a computation done in one of the models may be simulated in another model with at most a polynomial slowdown). In contrast, I hardly see how you can do the same with a computer architecture, which is just a design (engineering) that leads to an actual implementation of a computer.

Comment: I think this is a real answer. however, havent seen a paper or book or authority that points out how similar the von neumann architecture is to a Turing machine.... it does not seem to be a widely recognized idea.... to me one is the physical version of the theoretical version, and objections amt to hairsplitting....

Comment: @MassimoCafaro: Ok, thanks for explaining to me the difference between math and engineering. I updated my answer to reflect the difference.

Comment: @AndrejBauer A computational model, no matter whether practical or theoretical, should allow to model *what* is computed, and give clear semantics as to *how* it is computed. The way I understand it, von-Neumann-architecture is a design principle telling us how we should organise elements of a given machine model in hardware. So I agree: von-Neumann is not a computational model but can/has to be used in conjunction with one.